# Shower head holder with teeth

Tags: shower

this is probably a very basic question, but I am not able to find an answer by googling. I am trying to replace the shower head at my new place, but the connector that goes to the pipe has "teeth" (picture attached). The shower head holders that I have seen at my local store do not have these teeth; they just look like pretty standard screw-on.

My question is where can I find a shower head holder that with "teeth" that will fit the base of my shower pipe?

P.S. It also looks like this "teeth" connector attached the pipe was not originally there, as the color of the metal is different, and I see what appears to be silicone-based adhesive.

[image: shower head mount with teeth]

Comment: The whole grey/teeth part should unscrew from the bent pipe.  I can't think of a reason a shower head would need those teeth/gear part.

Comment: Agreed, just remove the "toothy" part. it is a part of the old shower head and does not need to be there.

Comment: Most plumbing connections require two wrenches.  One to hold and one to turn.  Twisted off pipe is not good.

Comment: Thank you, @crip659 and RMDman! That's what I was thinking. I won't be able to unscrew it using my hands only. I will get a couple of wrenches.

Comment: Try using a non scratching grip on the shower arm. A strap wrench would best. Alternatively use a rag or washcloth between the jaws of pliers or pipe wrench. The threads on the shower arm are parallel and seal with a soft seal (washer) so they should not be too tight. When you put on the new shower head the threads do NOT need PTFE tape or pipe dope because the end of the shower arm is pressed against a soft seal in the shower head. Don't tighten this hard but just barely firm. This joint is not under any pressure when the shower is off and only under reduced pressure when the shower is on.

Comment: The seal could conceivably be stuck to the end of the shower arm. If so, remove the old seal. The new shower head is supposed to have a seal in it. Cover the drain with a towel or other cover so that nothing goes down the drain. A towel or rubber mat on the floor under the shower arm is a good idea in case you drop a wrench.

Comment: A dropped wrench on toes not good either.